# How to add module to environment module? So I can load it using module load

Tags: module, ubuntu-18.04, environment-modules

When I run module avail, I got:

```
--------------------------------- /usr/share/modules/modulefiles ---------------------------------
dot  module-git  module-info  modules  null  use.own  

--------------------------------- /usr/share/modules/modulefiles ---------------------------------
dot  module-git  module-info  modules  null  use.own
```

And I notice people uses module to load gcc5 cuda10.0 by `module load gcc5 cuda10.0` . Like this person did in:
[Slurm sbatch for a PyTorch script draining node; gres/gpu: count changed for node node002 from 0 to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60729725/slurm-sbatch-for-a-pytorch-script-draining-node-gres-gpu-count-changed-for-nod)

How do I add things like gcc5 and cuda10.0 to my modules?

Answer (score 1):

You need to craft these modulefiles by hand if you manually install these specific software or the specific version of these software.

If you use a package manager like [Spack](https://spack.io/) or [EasyBuild](https://easybuild.io/) to build the software, those tools can also generate the corresponding modulefiles to use the software they built and install.